# Add personal parameters at topic-subscriber callback

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to add a personal parameter (or more than 1) at the normal subscribe function?
..(for example passing an integer that i'd like to use in the callback)
how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64664/add-personal-parameters-at-topic-subscriber-callback/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-06-10**:
Whats the use-case for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, please see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/?answer=63998#post-id-63998) for almost exactly the same use-case :-)

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-10**:
thanks!!! this is exactly what i need!.....but,sincerely it's not completely clear: a small explanation would be really appreciated :)

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-06-10**:
Glad to help! .....but,sincerely your comment is not completely clear: a small explanation of what you don't understand would be really appreciated ;-) Just have a look at boost::bind and tell us what is not clear.

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-10**:
i'm not a computer scientist and so not an expert of programming stuff: i read the documentation but is not clear (at least for me). i'd like to understand what this function does and how i can use it for my purposes

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-10**:
(i have to declare n subscriber (with a for cycle for instance) that writes the data in a vector (of size n)...so i have to pass an integer to the same callback to increment the position in the vector

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-10**:
my problem is explained better here: http://answers.ros.org/question/64747/write-in-a-vector-through-the-same-ros-callback-using-boostbind-c/